# Term for someone receiving pastoral care

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, nouns

I'm currently writing a manual on pastoral care in a Church community.

In our cultural context, we use the term "pastor" not only for the traditional role of a community leader but also for anyone providing pastoral care - this works well and is an established part of our vocabulary.

Where I'm struggling is in finding a good word to describe the person receiving the care. Simply using "person" is a little unclear in many contexts (as you may imagine, many point of the manual will involve the person receiving pastoral care and a number of others). Being overly etymological and going back to the root meanings, I'd be left with terms involving sheep and flocks, all of which sound impersonal and condescending when applied to an individual. I'd like to avoid adjectival phrases like "person receiving care" or similar.

We've used the term "pastee" in jest for a number of years (for trans-Atlantic readers, this is funny because a "pasty" is also a delicious foodstuff) but if I have to resort to using it in the manual then it will need a little explanation!

Can anyone offer any suggestions?

**TL; DR**

Can you suggest a noun meaning "person receiving pastoral care" that isn't:
 1. Clumsy
 2. Condescending

Comment: Be a little retro, and call the person a **soul**.

Comment: I'd say "recipient" http://www.thefreedictionary.com/recipient

Comment: What type of care are they receiving? (For example, some pastors provide counseling; some deacons meet financial needs or serve as a handyman; some laypersons will prepare food).

Comment: Towards another of your points: I do not consider "sheep" to be condescending; it was fitting for King David in Ps. 23 or Ps. 100.

Comment: Good question: not sure the answer is going to help. We're talking in terms of general pastoral care, covering everything from being a mentor, to praying for someone who's sick, to offering counselling and advice.

Comment: 'Patient', which is what a mental health professional would use, is probably too clinical a term. Counsellors tend to use 'client', at least in my experience.

Comment: I see your difficulty. There probably is no generic term for one who is mentored (mentee is a poor back-formation in my opinion); no term for one prayed for; no term for one who receives advice. "Counselee" might do for one who is counseled, but you're probably trying to come up with a single word that encompasses any recipient of care.

Comment: If *pastoral care* is the full range of activities a pastor brings to his congregation, isn't the recipient simply a *congregant*?

Comment: Does your church have members? Will the manual be written for members only? Regular attenders who are not members? Members of the community who are neither members nor regular attenders?

Comment: @bib - good thinking, but "pastor" is being used more generally for anyone in the congregation giving pastoral care, so the pastor is most likely themselves a congregant.

Comment: @rajah9, for the most part the pastors in the sense of the document are members: the recipients of the pastoral care are sometimes members and sometimes regular attenders. I think you and others have basically helped me come to the conclusion that no, there's not a good existing word to describe what I'm talking about - submit that as an answer and I'll give you the credit due!

Comment: Would suppliant work?

Answer (score 2):

In the classic psychoanalyst model, such a person was called the *analysand* (as opposed to a patient). However, I can't think of any way to make this relevant to your question.

Nonprofessional therapists (those without doctorates) often refer to those seeking their services as *clients*. But that doesn't seem to fit either.

The term accepted by the National Alliance for the Mentally Ill is *consumer* of services, but that seems too broad.

Someone I know received pastoral care on a couple of occasions and was simply referred to as *parishioner* X.

Answer (score 1):

Consider, [***recipient***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=care+recipient%2Ccare+recipients&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccare%20recipient%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccare%20recipients%3B%2Cc0)

> A person or thing that receives or is awarded something.
>
> [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/recipient)
>
> *Coordinate Pastoral Care ministries; ensure effective processes designed to build strong communication and emotional support for pastoral care recipients, caregivers and volunteers.*
>
> [St. John's Cathedral](http://jaxcathedral.org/newsite/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Job-Description_Final_April-11-2016_Director-of-Parish-Life.pdf)

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted as that seems a little harsh. For my money, though, it is pretty impersonal and very passive (the latter consideration wasn't part of my spec of course).

Comment: I've up-voted it: I thought of exactly the same word. You say that it's "impersonal and very passive", but I don't agree that it is.  You asked for a term suitable for use in your manual.  You yourself referred to "the person receiving pastoral care" - that is a *recipient*!  You could introduce the term early in the manual as the "recipient of pastoral care"; "care recipient" or something similar, and then contract it subsequently to "recipient".